# What happens to kernel when an user space process is executed by CPU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

If kernel is the only process, then the ALU will keep on executing the kernel instructions.

1. Now, does the program counter always contain kernel space instructions ?

Now, When another process A is started, my understanding is that the kernel loads A's starting address into program counter.

2. At this point the ALU will now start executing A's instructions. What happens to the kernel? Does the context of the kernel is saved to memory and restored back after the completion of process A. It was the kernel who loaded the PC with process A's address. Now, who will load the kernel's address back into PC after completion ? (I believe resource manager, scheduler, etc.. everything is a part of kernel.)

When the ALU is executing process A, the kernel is not in running state.

3. Does it mean my system is not running the kernel at that instance of time ?

(This may sound silly, but I really don't understand how this works)

4. Also, the kernel is responsible for drawing to monitor. So, at any time T(micro or nano second), when the ALU is not executing the kernel instruction how the monitor still displays everything or why it is not turned off ?

Comment: ALUs aren't capable of executing instructions by themselves.  Fetch-decode-execute is done by the CPU control logic, the ALU only performs arithmetic suboperations under the control of signals from the control unit.  Not all instructions even involve arithmetic.  So everywhere you said "ALU" the word "CPU" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: 'If kernel is the only process, then the ALU will keep on executing the kernel instructions.' - no.  The kernel is a state-machine of code and data.  It is entered from processes when those processes need kernel action, or asynchronously from drivers when devices need action.  If there are no processes left, the kernel will, (typically), halt the core/s, waiting for a driver interrupt.  Until that happens, there is nothing executing and the cores/buses are idle.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts change the CPU context.  A device interrupt can cause driver code to run on schedule (e.g. drawing), and a timer interrupt is often used to perform task scheduling.

In fact, every OS call has to be implemented as a software interrupt (sometimes optimized using e.g. `sysenter`) because user code can't change the context back to kernel.  Specifically, kernel code needs to run privileged (on x86 architecture this is called "ring 0"), and non-kernel code can't change the privilege level.